# Using react-testing-library + jest, why is my code coverage so high despite no "expect"?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, react-testing-library

I'm attempting to up our test coverage in our app and am a bit confused about the combo of react-testing-library + jest and how they determine coverage.

I'm attempting to test one of our app's components using the following:

```
import React from 'react'

import { BrandColors } from '@components/settings/BrandColors'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing'
import { SettingsDocument } from '@generated/graphql'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { getMockResponse, schemaWithMocks } from '@utils/apollo-mocks'

it('shows a skeleton when loading', async () => {
  const data = await getMockResponse(schemaWithMocks, SettingsDocument)
  const mock = {
    request: {
      query: SettingsDocument
    },
    result: { data }
  }

  const { container } = render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[mock]}>
      <BrandColors />
    </MockedProvider>
  )
})
```

I've been developing tests while running `--watch` so I get immediate feedback every time I save. I was surprised to see that what I wrote above immediately gave me 94% coverage on the `<BrandColors>` component despite no `expect` assertions.

What gives?

Comment: Can it be that coverage checks for all of the code that was ran during a test, and not just the code that's in expect?

Comment: Yes, the code cooverage means what % of all of the executable statements were run during the test.

Comment: This makes sense. So by rendering the entire component, all the happy path LOC are executed and the number is sky-high.